# How to use a Tkinter button to return a value and then change text depending on button clicked

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a D&D character creator where the user is asked a series of questions and the character is generated based on their answers. All the questions have 2 possible answers. What question is asked next is dependent on previous answers.

I have used Tkinter to make my user interface and I am trying to  update the frame containing the question label and 2 answer buttons each time and answer is selected, and get the answer selected added to a list of all answers given.

I have tried setting each answer button to reset the frame using the frame.forget() method, and to get them to add the button name to an answers list. However, I cannot find a way to update the text to the next question as the if statement runs immediately (before a button has been clicked to update answerList)
Code:

```
#the refreshQuestionnaire() function resets question, answer1, and answer2 to their default states

answerList = []
question = ttk.Label(questionnaire, text='filler question')
answer1 = ttk.Button(questionnaire, text = 'answer1', command= lambda: [qu.getAnswer('a1', answerList), refreshQuestionnaire(questionnaireFrame)])
answer2 = ttk.Button(questionnaire, text = 'answer2', command= lambda: [qu.getAnswer('a2', answerList), refreshQuestionnaire(questionnaireFrame)])

q_and_a_dict = qu1()     #qu1() gets the first question as a dict of the question and two answers
question['text'] = q_and_a_dict['Qu']
answer1['text'] = q_and_a_dict['ans1']
answer2['text'] = q_and_a_dict['ans2']

if answerList == ['a1']:
    q_and_a_dict = qu.upCloseQU()
    question['text'] = q_and_a_dict['Qu']
    answer1['text'] = q_and_a_dict['ans1']
    answer2['text'] = q_and_a_dict['ans2']
    main.update()
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Everything that happens as a result of clicking a button needs to go into its `command=` function.  A `lambda` isn't going to work for what you're trying to do here, you need a regular `def` function so that you're able to perform assignments.